# how to get data from csv file to use for multiple threads

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, csv, automation

I am creating an automanipulator on android emulator and get data from csv file for text input. I want to run multiple emulator threads and import data at the same time, repeating the whole process until all the data in the file is used up.

```
import subprocess
import uiautomator2 as u2
import sys
import threading
from time import sleep
import csv

def start_memu_emulator(instance_id):
 # code
                   
def sort_windows():
 # code

def start_app(emulator):
 # code

def begin(emulator):
    # Input FirstName
    emulator.send_keys(first_name)

    emulator.implicitly_wait(10.0)
    emulator(resourceId="lastName").click()

    # Input LastName
    emulator.send_keys(last_name)

    emulator.implicitly_wait(10.0)
    emulator(text="Next").click()

    sleep(10)

def stop_memu_emulator():
 # code

def run_functions(emulator):
    sort_windows()
    start_app(emulator)
    begin(emulator)
    stop_memu_emulator()

with open('name.csv', 'r') as file:
    # Create a CSV reader object
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    
    # Iterate over the rows of the CSV file
    for row in reader:
        first_name = row["Name"]
        last_name = row["Pass"]    


# Ask the user for the number of emulator threads to run
num_threads = int(input("Enter the number of emulator threads to run: "))

# Start the desired number of MEmu emulator instances
for i in range(num_threads):
    instance_id = i
    start_memu_emulator(instance_id)

# Run the adb devices command and capture the output
output = subprocess.run(['adb', 'devices'], capture_output=True)
# Split the output into lines and remove the first line (which is a header)
lines = output.stdout.decode().strip().split('\n')[1:]

# Parse the lines into columns using the csv.reader function
reader = csv.reader(lines, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

# Extract the serial numbers from the first column of each row
serials = [row[0].split('\t')[0] for row in reader]
print('Devices series:', serials)

# Connect to each emulator instance using the serial number
emulators = []
for serial in serials[:num_threads]:
    emulator = u2.connect(serial)
    emulators.append(emulator)

# Use threading to run the start_gmail function on each emulator
threads = []
for emulator in emulators:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_functions, args=(emulator,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to finish
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

How can multiple threads get data on the same file without overlapping with other threads? Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: p/s: I thought about using multiple csv files and using if else, but that would be very limited and confusing.

Comment: Do you want every thread to process all CSV data or are you trying to implement some kind of chunking? Bear in mind that once you've got your dictionary from csv.Dict_reader() that it's visible in all threads

Comment: @Fred i want it to be like: thread 1 get line 1 data, thread 2 get line 2 data,... and take each line like that until all the lines are exhausted. Sorry for my stupid description but I'm a newbie, hope you understand

Comment: Iterate over the DictReader() return value (which will be a Python dictionary) then start your thread with a reference to the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a CSV and you want discrete threads to process each record/row in the CSV file.

Let's say we have this CSV file:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

...then...

```
from csv import DictReader
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def process(line):
    print(line)

with open('foo.csv') as data:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as tpe:
        tpe.map(process, DictReader(data))
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}
{'A': '4', 'B': '5', 'C': '6'}
```